# Css style for <a> in a table doesn't work

Tags: html, css

Hi i have this piece of CSS:

```
tbody:hover td {
   color: transparent;
   text-shadow: 0 0 3px #aaa;
}

tbody:hover tr:hover td {
   color: #444;
   text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
}
```

When i hover a row of a table i want that the other rows of that table become transparent. This CSS work for the normal td filled with text, but for the td filled with link(a tag) it doesn't work. I can't find why.

This is a part of the HTML code

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Untitled.txt</td>
        <td>File di prova</td>
        <td><a href='/comment/comment.php?idF=182' style='color: black;'>Leggi i commenti</a></td>          
        <td><a href='get_file.php?id=182' style='color: black;'>Download</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Share html code please

Comment: if i remove the tbody:hover, the css doesn't work at all

Comment: you need to set the anchor color to inherit a { color: inherit} so that it takes the parent's color

Comment: remove that inline style from html code for anchor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple. Your a tags have inline styles. Those have a high ranking in css hierarchy. So the reason why this doesn't work is this piece of code:

```
style='color: black;'
```

Remove the inline style and apply it via class instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, im a noob

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's possible to make others transparent using CSS only (CSS can not effect on previous siblings). however, you can't use `:hover` twice, unless you do something like this:

```
tbody tr:hover > td, tbody tr:hover > td a {
    color: #444;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
}
```

In order to find a solution for the transparency issue, you may try to use [`nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to decide which child will be changed on hover. for example:

```
tbody tr:nth-child(1):hover {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 3px #aaa;
}
```

You can also decide what to do when the element is not hovered, example:

```
tbody tr:nth-child(1):not(:hover) {
    // If element is not hovered
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 3px #aaa;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `inherit` property:

```
a {
    color: inherit !important; //important just for extra measure
}
```

Comment: thank you, i dont mark it as the solution because there was also another more important error in the HTML and another one solve it

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put the a tag in your CSS too  .

```
tbody:hover td, tbody:hover td a {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #aaa;
}
```